# Style of merged cells when First column option is checked in a Word table

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, table-styles

I have a table in Word 2013 which uses a built-in style (“Grid Table 1 Light – Accent 11”) and has *Header row* and *First column* options checked. The table has two columns, and one of its rows is merged to form one cell. Like this:

[image: Sample table with merged cells]

The problem is the merged cell on row 2 inherits 'first column' formatting. I want this cell to have normal formatting, as appears in the second column, i.e. not in bold.

How can I change the merged cell's settings to have normal style, without unchecking the *First column* option?

---

**UPDATE:** I'm **not** asking for a workaround. It is **not** sufficient to select the cell's content a make non-bold. This just *doesn't work* in respect to further processing, such as plain copying and pasting the content somewhere else. The problem is, that *being rendered bold* is **inherited** from the first-column style. I really *need to* get rid of this first-column style.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand the issue - you can just select the text in the cell and change its formatting, can't you?

Comment: @aganju Technically, yes. However, the text in my example *inherits* the first-column style, and as such making it non-bold *in fact* makes the text itself *bold*. This behavior manifests itself whenever you copy & paste the text to some place elsewhere.

Comment: @OndrejTucny I tried to duplicate what I thought you are referring to, but could not. Could you describe the steps that you take and just before you take the step that causes headache and describe the behavior you desire before your action. Then the step you take that causes the undesirable result. Also, is this a Word Table, or an inserted Excel Table (spreadsheet) in a Word doc?

Answer (score -1):

If you make your table in excel, and you have different First columns and second columns (as in your example) then if you apply a conditional formatting with the rule (if you start at position A2) and you use this formatting rule

Formatting rule image:

[image]

then your end result will look like this

[image]

Then you can include the excel document into word, and all should work.

[example excel document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu4zsmw6i658pfe/Example.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: This question is about Word, and **not** a cheap way of earning a bounty based on an Excel-related answer.

Comment: No, it just is a working way to solve the problem. I don't care about the bounty, I just knew how to answer this.

Answer (score -1):

click in the field you want adjusted; press SHIFT + END; press CTRL + B.

That will make that cell non-bold, without changing any of the 'first-col', etc. settings.

I would expect this also to behave on further pages correctly; but I have no way to test that right now.

Alternatively, you can (instead of merging) shrink the first column for this line to width = 0.01 and make the vertical bar invisible, so it becomes invisible. What is currently a 'merged cell' would then be a standard column 2 cell.

Comment: This is a workaround, but **not** an answer to my question.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Do you want to teach the merged cell to behave like it's a member of column 2 (and not column 1)? You can do that by - instead of merging - shrinking the first column for this line to width = 0, so it becomes invisible (or 0.01 and make the vertical bar invisible). What is currently a 'merged cell' would then be a standard column 2 cell. Is that what you try?

Comment: That doesn't work either. Word won't let you collapse a cell to zero width. At least there would space for border remain.